# TKinter running through a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

For a basic example, suppose I want to run a list of questions and for each question i want a button to be pressed which will append a value "yes" or "no" to the list.

```
window = tk.Tk()
app=tk.Frame(window)
app.grid()

response_list = []

y_button = tk.Button(app,text="yes", command=lambda x="yes": appendResponse(x))

n_button = tk.Button(app,text="no", command=lambda x="no": appendResponse(x))

questions=["q1","q2","q3"]

window.mainloop()
```

How can i make the window stay open and display all the questions until there is a complete list of answers?

Comment: you have `app.mainloop()` right?

Comment: I am unsure that the question you're asking is valid. What have you tried to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like the following:

```
#STARTS HERE
#Label with question
lbl1 = tk.Label(app, text="Are you a human?")
lbl1.grid()

def appendResponse(resp):
    global response_list

    questionNo = len(response_list)

    if questionNo % 3 == 0:
        lbl1.configure(text="Is this a valid question?")

    elif questionNo % 3 == 1:
        lbl1.configure(text="Is there a better way to do this?")

    elif questionNo % 3 == 2:
        lbl1.configure(text="Is this what you wanted to do?")

    response_list.append(resp)

#FINISHES HERE
```